# Merging data from SQL azure database to elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, azure-sql-database

I have an SQL SERVER database hosted on azure,
i want to migrate data to elastik stack, for the configuration of my logstash file , I tried this code : https://medium.com/@erangadulshan.14/pushing-relational-data-to-elasticsearch-using-logstash-jdbc-input-plugin-48af81ed1000 and its doesnt work, i have installed sql server driver msodbcsql17 but doesnt work, (I don't have the path of any jar file ) 
What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference this tutorial: [How to copy SQL Server data to Elasticsearch using LogStash](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-copy-sql-server-data-to-elasticsearch-using-logstash/).
As a developer working with SQL Server there was a need to import data from the database to Elasticsearch and analyze data in Kibana.

As Elasticsearch is an open source project built with Java and handles mostly other open source projects, documentations on importing data from SQL Server to ES using LogStash.

This tutorial shared how to import SQL Server data to Elasticsearch (version 6.2) using LS and verify the result on Kibana.

Hope this helps.